# Python convert Excel File (xls or xlsx) to/from ODS

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, openoffice-api, ods

I've been scouring the net to find a Python library or tool that can converts an Excel file to/from ODS format, but haven't been able to come across anything.

I need the ability to input and output data in either format. We don't need to worry about merged cells, formulas or anything non-straightforward.

Comment: Any reason why the Python Excel libraries (http://www.python-excel.org/) plus the odslib (https://code.google.com/p/odslib-python/) won't work?

Comment: Not at all. I just didn't want to re-invent the wheel if something already existed. I'm happy to write something to do the job and release it to the public, if nothing of the sort exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have libreoffice installed, you can do a python execution wrapper around its headless mode:

```
$ /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless --invisible -convert-to ods /home/cwgem/Downloads/QTL_Sample_data.xls 
convert /home/cwgem/Downloads/QTL_Sample_data.xls -> /home/cwgem/QTL_Sample_data.ods using OpenDocument Spreadsheet Flat XML
$ /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless --invisible -convert-to xls /home/cwgem/QTL_Sample_data.ods 
convert /home/cwgem/QTL_Sample_data.ods -> /home/cwgem/QTL_Sample_data.xls using
```

Which would be a bit easier than trying to do it through the library route.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a way to go.

Comment: Note that this command does not work if libreoffice is running already.

Comment: If the executable on windows is `soffice.exe`, then its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to convert an xlsx file to an ods file with this method :

1. install [pyexcel-xlsx](https://pypi.org/project/pyexcel-xlsx/)
2. install [pyexcel-ods3](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyexcel-ods3)

And use the following code :

```
from pyexcel_ods3 import save_data
from pyexcel_xlsx import get_data

dataXlsx = get_data("file.xlsx")
save_data("file.ods", dataXlsx)
```

**Attention** : the colors/design of the xlsx file is removed in the ouput ods file...so that it is not a real success.