# Combine multiple .xls into one file in different sheets without changing format

Tags: python, excel, libreoffice

I'm using python to process some data. In the beginning, I have an .ods file with many sheets. I need to edit cells inside each sheets and save it as a new file. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285650/2363712 to achieve generating new files while keeping the same format by preparing separate .xls reference files from the original .ods and then copy/edit these files with python.

```
class xls_form:
'''
modify the original file start from row 3
'''
    def __init__(self, in_filename="ref_excel_form3.xls"):
        self.inBook = xlrd.open_workbook(in_filename, formatting_info=True, on_demand=True)
        # Copy the workbook, and get back the style
        # information in the `xlwt` format
        self.outBook, self.outStyle = copy2(self.inBook)

    def write2(self, sheet_idx, x, y, val):
        insheet = self.inBook.sheet_by_index(sheet_idx)
        xf_index = insheet.cell_xf_index(3, y)
        saved_style = self.outStyle[xf_index]

        self.outBook.get_sheet(sheet_idx).write(x, y, val, saved_style)
    
    def fill_dic_in(self, sheet_idx, dic_data, col_map):
        col_i = 0
        for k, v in dic_data.items():
            for k1, v1 in v.items():
                row_i = 3
                for val in v1:
                    self.write2(sheet_idx, row_i, col_map[col_i], val)
                    row_i += 1
                col_i += 1

    def export(self, out_filename="write_excel_form3_out.xls"):
        self.outBook.save(out_filename)
```

My question now is that I need to combine these modified .xls files back to one .ods file with several sheets (also keeping the same format). I know libreoffice can be used in cmd to transfer by [Python convert Excel File (xls or xlsx) to/from ODS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257032/python-convert-excel-file-xls-or-xlsx-to-from-ods) one by one. Is there a way to combine them into one file? Thank you for any suggestion but No pandas please :)

Comment: Some things to try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48713862/5100564, https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/multiple-csv-ods-files-into-individual-tabs-in-single-spreadsheet-closed/36207/2, https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=77069. I would choose the second link personally, but you would need to translate the Basic into Python-UNO.

Comment: @JimK I tried the first solution and it works! Thank you~